# How to configure two app server nodes to connect to same elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one code base to connect elastic search (localhost:9200) for the full-text-search feature. We deployed this code on two different machines (m1 & m2) under load balancing server. In this case, how to configure ES in 2 different machines to connect ES and index should reflect both sides.

I am using Elasticsearch v 5.1.2

Machine 1

```
cluster.name: production
node.name: database
```

Machine 2

```
cluster.name: production
node.name: app
```

Above setting worked on ES v 1.7.1

**Question?

**What configuration should I do to make it work on ES v5.1.2?**

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are both machines on the same local network?

Comment: Yes @RoiHatam, both machines on the same local network.

Comment: You will see all data on both machines then

Comment: Ya, we are searching keyword(ES) from 2 machine. Indexing should reflect in both machines while calling Search API.

Comment: I have 2 different nodes under the same cluster name, if I create an index in node1 then that should accessible in node2 and vice-verse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming these nodes aren't a part of same cluster.

Try http://MACHINE_1_IP:9200/_cat/nodes?v and check if all nodes are listed as part of cluster.

If they are not - just a quick guess, have you looked at network.host [setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/modules-network.html) ? It binds to local loop by default ( That maybe something introduced in 2 + )

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I ran below API to check the nodes

#From machine 1
curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v
ip        heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role master name
127.0.0.1           11          94   7    0.91    0.44     0.27 mdi       *      node1

#From machine 2
curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v
ip        heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role master name
127.0.0.1           10          99   0    0.06    0.07     0.01 mdi       *      node2

Comment: Thanks,  Now cluster able to communicating each other by setting network. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/modules-network.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using network-module setting ([ref](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/modules-network.html)).
Update the elasticsearch.yml on both app server by keeping same cluster name and different node name

EX :

Server_1

update the elasticseach.yml

```
cluster.name: Production
node.name: APP
network.host: [server_1_IP, _local_]
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [server_1_IP, server_2_IP]
```

On Server_2

update the elasticseach.yml

```
cluster.name: Production
node.name: DB
network.host: [server_2_IP, _local_]
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [server_1_IP, server_2_IP]
```